# Z3 (z3py) "elim_and" option of the "simplify()" function always enabled for bit vectors

Tags: z3, simplify, z3py

I would like to use the simplify() function of z3py, but without changing the bitwise and '&' to a bitwise or '|'.

There seem to exist an option called "elim_and" to the simplify function, but I cannot manage to have it to work for bitwise operations. The function help_simplify() states:

> elim_and (bool) conjunctions are rewritten using negation and disjunctions (default: false)

```
>>> from z3 import *
>>> x = BitVec('x', 8)
>>> y = BitVec('y', 8)
>>> z = x & y
>>> z
x & y
>>> simplify(z)
~(~x | ~y)
>>> simplify(z, elim_and=False)
~(~x | ~y)
```

I would like the result to be "x & y".
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. Note that `elim_and` is targeted for booleans, not bit-vectors:

```
>>> from z3 import *
>>> a = Bool("a")
>>> b = Bool("b")
>>> simplify(And(a, b))
And(a, b)
>>> simplify(And(a, b), elim_and=True)
Not(Or(Not(a), Not(b)))
```

There's no equivalent option to `simplify` that controls this for bit-vectors. In fact, the translation to disjunction happens even before you call the simplifier, see here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/ast/rewriter/bv_rewriter.cpp#L1980-L1988

Answer (score 0):

`elim_and` is for Boolean expressions, not for bit-vectors. Z3 doesn't have an option to disable specific rewrite rules I'm afraid.